# Cannot get typeahead.js basic example to work

Tags: asp.net, typeahead.js

I am copying 'The Basics' example from http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
and cannot get this to work in a plain HTML page.

In fact I have tried many code samples from all over the web, and none seem to work. This makes me think that I am using incorrect versions of the script libraries (see below).

Here is the 'The Basics' example in my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" />
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js" />
    <script src="typeahead.js" />

    <script>

        var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
            return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substringRegex;

                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                        matches.push({ value: str });
                    }
                });

                cb(matches);
            };
        };

        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
           'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
           'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
           'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
           'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
           'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
           'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
           'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
           'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
            ];

        $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
           name: 'states',
           displayKey: 'value',
           source: substringMatcher(states)
        });

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="the-basics">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the above, nothing happens when I type in the textbox.

Have I got my script references correct? As you can see I am referencing v1.11.0 of jQuery.
My local version of bootstrap.min.js is v3.1.1. My local version of typeahead.js is 0.10.2

I have tried in IE9 and Chrome 22.x

Very grateful for any help.

Martin

Comment: so how did you solve...?

Comment: The following was missing from the first line of the script block (and also from the example). My jQuery is not that good!        $(document).ready(function () {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following first line was missing from  the script block (and also from the example). My jQuery is not that good!

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

    var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                    matches.push({ value: str });
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
       'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
       'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
       'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
       'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
       'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
       'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
       'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
       'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
       name: 'states',
       displayKey: 'value',
       source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I created  a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmccowat/J6SHJ/3/) which uses the typeahed from cdnjs and seems to work. I know there was an older version but this one is version [0.10.2](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) as you mention you were using.

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.bundle.min.js
```